# What do you mean when you say 'representing a set'?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As you know there are two ways to 'representing a set' ie Roster and set builder form. But I want to know What do you mean when you say 'representing a set'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably overthinking this. There's no technical meaning behind it, as far as I know. It's just a way of saying "we can define/describe a set and its members in these ways."

For example, consider the set

$$S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$

We can equivalently define $S$ by

$$S = \{x \in \Bbb Z \mid 1 \le x \le 10 \}$$

Roster form is the first way of writing the set: listing each element, either explicitly as above or implicitly. (Implicitly would be if I wrote $S = \{1,2,3,\cdots,10\}$, because "the pattern is obvious." As you might imagine if $S$ went all the way up to $100$ it would be cumbersome to write each element literally.)

The second way I wrote $S$ is the set-builder notation. We simply state that the members of our set $S$ are elements $x$ of another set (what that set is might be clear from context, here I have $x \in \Bbb Z$ to clarify the elements are integers for clarity), meeting some condition or set of conditions. In this case, our condition is that $x$ (which is an integer) is at most $10$ and at least $1$.

---

All these do is simply offer alternative ways to describe the set $S$ and what elements are in it. Each have their uses. For example, set-builder is often briefer, but (especially for small finite sets) roster form can be easier to follow. Set-builder might allow for a clearer overarching description of what $S$ actually is. For example, if $S= \{1,9,25,49,\cdots\}$, it might not be immediately obvious that $S$ is simply the set of squares of odd positive integers, $S = \{n^2 \in \Bbb N \mid n = 2k+1, k\in \Bbb N\}$.

And of course not all sets are "countable" or "listable" in the sense that enumerating them is pointless. Even with the implicit pattern idea communicated by "$\cdots$", try to enumerate all of the elements of the interval $[0,1]$. You can't because $[0,1]$ has a cardinality greater than that of the integers (you'll learn the consequences of this later on as you study set theory and what exactly it means in a rigorous sense), and thus you can't describe the interval in roster notation. You'll have to use to set-builder notation there:

$$[0,1] = \{ x\in \Bbb R \mid 0 \le x \le 1 \}$$